# How to train a visual attention model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision

In version 11.1 there is a new layer type `SequenceAttentionLayer[]`. I'm interested in how might this be used to train a recurrent [visual attention model](http://torch.ch/blog/2015/09/21/rmva.html) (see the below references).

Here are some examples of attention maps from a Visual Q&A network:

[image]

Unfortunately, none of the examples in the documentation indicate how recurrent networks in V11.1 might work with images, so here's my question:

Is object detection or related computer vision tasks with attentional models possible to implement in v11.1, and if so what are some examples?

**References:**

- http://ilab.usc.edu/publications/doc/Borji_Itti13pami.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05960

Comment: related to [How to visualize attention](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141542/1364)