# AttentionLayer what is it and why would it be used

Tags: neural-networks

Could anyone elaborate on the new Neural Network layer in Mathematica Verison 12:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AttentionLayer.html

AttentionLayer

The documentation is rather sparse on this.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Michel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
att = AttentionLayer["Dot"]
```

[image]

is the same as this:

```
net = NetGraph[
  {
   TransposeLayer[],
   DotLayer[],
   SoftmaxLayer[],
   DotLayer[]
   },
  {
   NetPort["Query"] -> 2,
   NetPort["Key"] -> 1 -> 2,
   2 -> 3,
   {3, NetPort["Value"]} -> 4
   }
  ]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[0];
input = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 2}];
query = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 2}];
```

```
att@<|"Key" -> input, "Value" -> input, "Query" -> query|>
```

> {{0.0650637,0.358659},{0.130756,0.397385},{0.467243,0.533}}

```
net@<|"Key" -> input, "Value" -> input, "Query" -> query|>
```

> {{0.0650637,0.358659},{0.130756,0.397385},{0.467243,0.533}}

Attention matrix:

```
SoftmaxLayer[]@(query.Transpose[input]) // TableForm
```

[image]

```
MatrixPlot[%, FrameLabel -> {{"Input", ""}, {"Query", ""}}]
```

[image]

Useful links:

[How to visualize attention?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/how-to-visualize-attention)

http://wac.36f4.edgecastcdn.net/0036F4/pub/www.wolfram.com/technology-conference/2018/Wednesday/2018-10-17_WTC_nn_framework.nb (slide 9)

http://www.wolfram.com/language/12/neural-network-framework/use-transformer-neural-nets.html